# ambiguity in understanding

Tags: grammar, punctuation, conjunctions, syntactic-analysis

I have some confusion on punctuations such as ,  ;  **and** conjuctions such as "and",  "but" in framing  the sentences.

In the above sentence, I used the conjunction **and** to denote that I have doubts on framing the sentences with both  punctuations and conjunctions. But the meaning can also be interpreted as confusion on punctuations (confusion is not given clearly on which aspect)  and the confusion on framing the sentences with conjunctions. I have faced this problem lot of times particularly when I do not know the real subject of the paragraph.

Could you please clarify my doubts by taking 2 to 3 sample of sentences.

Comment: You also need to work on space after punctuation and the strange fact that people from India, Sri Lanka and Pakistan do not write "I" with a capital "I"

Comment: @mplungjan I will work on your suggestions..

Comment: I still had to remove an extra space and add a missing space in your text :)

Comment: It's not clear what the question is about. Are you asking about the [use-mention distinction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction)?

Comment: Even after the edits, I still have no idea what this question is asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking about the scope of conjunctions such as *and*, and how ambiguities of scope might be resolved by punctuation.

The answer is that natural language is sometimes ambiguous. Spoken language is rarely ambiguous in practice, because of the metalinguistic mechanisms we have for making our meaning clear. But in written language we do not have these mechanisms. Punctuation sometimes helps, but is far less standardised than some people would like to pretend. So yes, in written language there are quite often  ambiguities of scope, and no universally agreed way to clarify them.

Comment: This is the answer I am looking from my childhood. Actually, I did not know how to express this question as I assumed language has been defined by clarity of scope and rules to avoid ambiguity, but your appreciated explanation made paradigm shift on me. Moreover, much knowledge on the specific topic results much less ambiguous. Most of the times, as no universal agreed way of using scope of conjunctions (I think these are only main attributes for confusions, if I am not wrong), we must have analytic approach and know author’s psychology, to enumerate increased lucidity